# Why $P(A)\cdot P(B \mid A) = P(B)\cdot P(A\mid B)$ for dependent events?

Tags: probability

Repeating the question

> Why $P(A)\cdot P(B \mid A) = P(B)\cdot P(A\mid B)$?

It makes total sense to me when we consider *independent* events. However, I struggle to understand why it also holds for dependent events.

If we assume that $P(A)\cdot P(B \mid A) = P(B)\cdot P(A\mid B)$ holds, then we also assume that the *order* of the events happening does not matter. **Why would we?**

Let's consider an example. Let $A,B$ be arbitrary two events. Let $P(A) := \frac{1}{3}$ and $P(B) := \frac{1}{3}$.

Suppose that if $A$ happens, then probability of of $B$ happening is $\frac{1}{5}$, or in other words, $P(B|A) = \frac{1}{5}$

And suppose that if $B$ happens, then probability of $A$ happening is $\frac{1}{6}$, or $P(A|B) = \frac{1}{6}$

We have

$$P(A) \cdot P(B\mid A) = \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{15} ≠ \frac{1}{18} = P(B) \cdot P(A\mid B)$$

So in this example, clearly, equality doesn't hold.

I assume it would be possible to come up with some "real world" examples which would also show that equality might not necessarily hold.

---

So what am I missing?

Comment: Both sides are equal to $P(A \cap B) \equiv P(B \cap A)$.

Comment: Your example has supposed a bunch of statements that are contradictory, that's all.

Comment: @NateEldredge Can you elaborate on what you mean by contradictory, please?

Comment: Simply that it is not possible to have events whose probabilities and conditional probabilities all have the values that you suppose.  Try to think of a real-life example of a random experiment where they all hold - you won't be able to.  More formally, try to actually define a probability space which has two events for which all those statements hold - you will fail.

Comment: Normally the $\sigma$-algebra that contains all events is not equipped with any order. So there is no such thing as "order of events". You could say that this part of reality is not modeled.

Comment: It's as if you were to say "Suppose that $x=6$, and suppose that $y=7$, and suppose that $x+y=3$".  Those suppositions can't all be true.

Comment: @NateEldredge, it's also like saying, I don't understand Pythagoras' $a^2 = b^2 + c^2$, because if you take $a=3, b=2, c=1$ it does not hold ;)

Answer (score 1):

> "Let's consider an example. Let $A,B$ be arbitrary two events. Let $P(A) := \frac{1}{3}$ and $P(B) := \frac{1}{3}$.
>
> Suppose that if $A$ happens, then probability of of $B$ happening is $\frac{1}{5}$, or in other words, $P(B|A) = \frac{1}{5}$"

From that you can conclude that the probability that **both events will occur** is $P(A)P(B\mid A)=\frac13\frac15=\frac1{15}$.

With *exactly the same reasoning* we come to the conclusion that the probability that **both events will occur** equals $P(B)P(A\mid B)$ so our final conclusion is that:$$P(A)P(B\mid A)=P(A\cap B)=P(B)P(A\mid B)$$

Answer (score 0):

note, that $P(A) P(B | A) = P(AB)$ is not a theorem, that holds by **definition** of conditional probability $P(B | A) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(A)}$. Similarly $P(A | B) = \frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$ by definition, and that implies the bayes formula $P(AB) = P(A) P(B | A) = P(B) P(A | B)$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a box contains 5 white and 3 black balls. You take 2 balls without replacement. So, the second ball color depends on the first ball color. Hence:
$$P(W_1\cap B_2)=P(W_1)\cdot P(B_2|W_1)=\frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{3}{7}=\frac{15}{56}\\
P(B_1\cap W_2)=P(B_1)\cdot P(W_2|B_1)=\frac38\cdot \frac57=\frac{15}{56}$$